In aviation what is official abbreviation for aerodynamics?
In aviation what is abbreviation for aerodynamics, maybe AE or AD?
list of aviation abberaviation

The one answer you have is questionable at best. If you're at all uncertain what the correct abbreviation is for any term, don't abbreviate. Better to be clear if a little verbose than introduce confusion.

I agree, I've never seen it abbreviated.


What is abbreviation for aerodynamics?

Based on practices, there is no generally accepted abbreviation for aerodynamics, not even one seldom used.
Take this book on aerodynamics, it contains 129 occurrences of the word, none abbreviated. It doesn't mean, an author cannot define their own abbreviation, but they will have to make it known, e.g:

The topic is about aerodynamics (shortened to aero from now on) ...

But what would they gain doing that, but introduce confusion?

Is AE used as Aerospace Engineering?

@22flower, yes it can be seen, similar to EE for electrical engineer(ing). Such abbreviations are not guaranteed to be immediately understood like say, GPS or AGL. They are usually defined where they are used. This is often industry lingo like PM for project manager or QA for quality assurer, OPEX for operational expenditures, etc.

Mostly I've just seen it shortened to "aero". I've never seen AD or AE. But it may vary between companies. @CatchAsCatchCan is right. If you aren't sure just spell it out.

It seems not exist..https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aviation,_avionics,_aerospace_and_aeronautical_abbreviations

Where I went to college “aero” was short for “aeronautical”. For example “aero engineering”.
